# Solve $g=\gcd⁡(a_0+A v,b_0+B u,n)$ with $g, u, v$ unknown and $g$ non-trivial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

How do we solve

$$g=\gcd⁡(a_0+A v,b_0+B u,n) \tag 1$$

where $a_0, b_0, A, B, n$ are given and $v, u, g \notin \{1, n\}$ are unknown? We may assume $\gcd(A, B) = 1$.

We can factor $n$ and then solve for $u, v$ using the divisors of $n$. **Are there any other ways?**

**Context:** This came about as a subproblem related to [this question on Reversing Karatsuba Multiplication for Integer Factoring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574551/reversing-karatsuba-multiplication-for-integer-factoring).

*Note:* Does $A = \alpha^k, B = \beta^m$ help with Eqn. (1)? The linked question gives $A, B$ in this structure, so if this somehow helps obtain $g$, that is sufficient.

**My method:**

$$\begin{align}
\exists r,s,t \in \mathbb{Z} & \text{ such that} \\
gr & = a_0 + \alpha^k v, \\
gs & = b_0 + \beta^m u, \\
gt & = n
\end{align}$$

Let $\gcd(n, \alpha - 1) \ne 1$. If not, we have a trivial divisor of $n$.

$$
\therefore (a_0 + \alpha^k v)s = (b_0 + \beta^m u)t \\
\implies a_0 s - b_0 t = \beta^m ut - \alpha^k vs \tag 2
$$

Suppose these two quantities on either side of Eqn. (2) equal $\delta \in \mathbb{Z}$

$$
a_0 s - b_0 t = \beta^m ut - \alpha^k vs = \delta \tag 3
$$

Such a solution is possible iff $\gcd(a_0, b_0)|\delta$ and $\gcd(\beta, \alpha)|\delta$. $\gcd(\beta, \alpha) = 1$ since we can assume $\gcd(A,B) = 1$ as given in the problem. Also, $\gcd(a_0, b_0) = 1$ because if it is not $1$ then we can take $(v,u)=(0,0)$ to solve $g = \gcd(a_0, b_0)$. So, we will assume the $\gcd(a_0, b_0)=1$.

Therefore, we may divide Eqn. (3) by $\delta$ to get:

$$\begin{align}
a_0 \bigg({s \over \delta}\bigg) - b_0 \bigg({t \over \delta}\bigg) = \beta^m \bigg({ut \over \delta}\bigg) - \alpha^k \bigg({vs  \over \delta}\bigg) = 1 \tag 4
\end{align}$$

and with a variable substitution $S = {s \over \delta}, T = {t \over \delta}, U = uT, V = vS$

$$
a_0 S - b_0 T = \beta^m U - \alpha^k V = 1 \tag 5
$$

We then solve

$$
a_0 S - b_0 T = 1 \tag {6.a}
$$

and then substitute in

$$
(\beta^m T)u - (\alpha^k S)v = 1 \tag {6.b}
$$

We can then put the solutions $(u,v)$ in Eqn. (1) and compute the non-trivial GCD, $g$.

Is this right?